# RedBeanPhp как рассчитать процент?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Суть проблемы: как оформить запрос к БД для RedBean !
Две таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соединил 2 таблицы

$products= \R::getAll("SELECT * FROM product JOIN pay ON product.pay_id = pay.sum_id");

```
Как сделать запрос для расчета % прибыли от продаж Например:
для id 1 = сумма с таблицы pay->sum по id 400+400 делим на цену товара / product->price 200 и умножаем на 100 % = получаем 400% продаж от суммы!
```

или

```
1)из табл pay>sum id1 = 400+400=800 сумма всех платежей
2)из табл product>price id1 = 200/100%=2 находим один процент
3) 800/2= 400% общая прибыль
```

набросал на данный код не работает

```
\R::getAll( "SELECT 
    product.*
    SUM(pay.sum)/product.price AS product.precent
FROM 
    product
    JOIN pay  ON product.paysystem_id = pay.pay_id
GROUP BY product.id");
```

Comment: какая ошибка? или данные вообще не выбираются?

Comment: вообще не выбираются

Comment: Что то сложно в твоем коде разобраться, попробуй достать данный из колонок которые тебе нужны и посчитать на php.